# Does Same Origin Policy still allows the serverside code to be executed?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, security, web, cors

I was thinking that the SOP blocked all requests to other domains conform their rules BEFORE sending it, but I did a simple example in my machine and It wasn't quite what I expected:

1- I have a local server listening to port 8000 that will print the POST data sent to `/api` URL.

2- I have another local server that serves a page with the following script: `fetch('http://localhost:8000/api', {method: 'post', body: 'Sending data.'});`. I changed the hostname to access this page with `foo.com` in my browser.

When I access `foo.com`, my cross domain request is executed and I can see the CORS error in Chrome Dev Tools:  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, but in the server console **the data was still received**. I thought that the SOP existed to solve exactly this kind of problem. The way it works, It only guarantee that you can't get the response back. Is that so? Almost all web documents doesn't quite say that.

What am I missing? Or is my example wrong somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly as you say, that's a big misunderstanding by many people of what the same origin policy protects against and how CORS works.

The request is indeed made, the server processes it and creates the response. It's only the browser that stops the client from being able to access the results. This may easily give way to attacks like CSRF.

Preflight requests also have a role, but the point doesn't change, the same origin policy doesn't stop the request, it stops the response from reaching the caller *in the browser*.

Comment: Now I finally can sleep again, thanks for the explanation. About the pre-flight-requests, what are they role? Why isn't everything a 'simple-request', I definitely don't get its value, given that the main point is for the browser just to block the response. The latency issue is a problem much worse, than calling a endpoint that will get the response ignored.

Comment: if the other domain made the DELETE operation, even if client can not access the results, the harm is done?

Comment: Wow, after so many years of programming I didn't know that. I knew the request needs to be made anyway to the server, but I thought the server will just not reply at all. Thanks